# Delayed countdown in DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have an app which uses DispatcherTimer to manage time, countdown things etc. and I do have multiple counters turned on while app is open. But the time is a little bit delayed, I'd say about 3-5 seconds per minute. This is part of the code I'm using:

```
DispatcherTimer ob = new DispatcherTimer();
ob.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

private void bob_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //Button starting countdown
    {
        ob.Start();
        tikOb = 140;
        ob.Tick += new EventHandler(ob_Tick);
    }

void ob_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tob.Text = tikOb.ToString();

        if (tikOb > 0)
        {
            tikOb--;
        }

        else
        {
            ob.Stop();
            tob.Text = "STOPPED";
            ob.Tick -= new EventHandler(ob_Tick);
        }



//Between these there is a code which is irrelevant in this case.

private void stopob_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //Button breaking countdown
    {
        ob.Tick -= new EventHandler(ob_Tick);
        ob.Stop();
        tob.Text = "ON";
    {
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening? Did I do anything wrong inside the code? Oh, I also have another one in the code which uses different variables etc. It's completely separated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DispatcherTimer is executed on the UI thread. If the UI thread is currently busy doing other work for more than the interval, it will delay the execution of the Timer event and invoke it once it is free of prior work. If you need more precise scheduling, you should go for a time than runs in the background, like `System.Threading.Timer` or `Task.Delay` which can be `await`ed, if you're using .NET 4.5 and above. If you use the `Timer` and then invoke UI thread logic, you will have to remember to marshal back work to the UI thread.